# Linking to built-in alarm of phone to the application

Tags: android, alarm

I am a beginner in android programming and currently I am doing an application that needs the use of alarm. I need to link the built-in alarm in the phone to my application but right now I am not sure on how to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185401/how-can-i-access-alarm-content-provider.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I think it's not really helpful to me.

Comment: That link answers your question: It's not possible (except on certain, older versions of Android). The Alarm API is not public, and neither is the ContentProvider that backs it.